# Java 10 DateTimeFormatter pattern symbols for "E" and "MMM" adding periods

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format, java-10

So in Java 8 the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E d MMM yyyy");
```

When applied in this manner:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
date.format(df);
```

Would produce something like this:

```
"Available on Thu 30 Aug 2018"
```

However, the exact same code when run in Java 10 produces the following:

```
"Available on Thu. 30 Aug. 2018"
```

Notice the periods after the day and month sections...

I'm well aware I can just replace the periods in the string but I really don't want to have to do that. I'm wondering why this change has occurred and if there is an alternative pattern?

I cannot find any reference to this change online.

**EDIT:**

As per Basil's answer below, it's not a Java version issue. It's a locale issue. The docker image with my code is running on a US locale and my machine on an Aus one :)

Comment: Maybe the interpretation of the locale has changed.  Try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E d MMM yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US)` or another locale and see if that works.

Comment: In Java 11, it prints `Sun 14 Oct 2018`. Not sure why it was changed in Java 10 and changed back in 11 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because I'm using the HotSpot JVM rather than Zulu?

Comment: Zulu is using [HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot), being based on [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK). What JIT compiler you use really should not impact localization.

Comment: `I'm well aware I can just replace the periods in the string`.... you maybe can't; if you end up dealing with multiple locales, or some other factors you could end up with embedded periods which you shouldn't remove.

Comment: As shown in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52809414/642706), run code to log your JVM version and default locale. Report back here by editing your Question. Actually, showing *all* the `System` properties would be useful here.

Comment: Here's the JDK 9 release note on the switch to using CLDR data by default: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8008577

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Verify `Locale`

Punctuation and related matters (abbreviation, spelling, order of elements) are defined as part of cultural norms. In Java, these cultural norms are specified by a `Locale`.

### Locale varied at runtime

One possible issue is that you are running code without specifying a `Locale` explicitly, which means you are relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default locale. That default may differ between runtime environments.

Log your default locale, to verify.

```
Locale.getDefault().toString()
```

Study the code example below to see how to specify your `Locale` explicitly. I recommend *always* making your `Locale` explicit (ditto for time zone, by the way).

### Definition varied at runtime

Note that a major change happened with regard to date-time localization with Java 9: [*JEP 252: Use CLDR Locale Data by Default*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252). At least for OpenJDK-based JVMs, the source of information about these cultural norms switched to the [*Common Locale Data Repository*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) provided by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium).

For the particular case discussed here, when using `Locale.US`, we see no difference, as you can see in code example below. But for some locales you may indeed see a difference between Java 8 and earlier versus Java 9 and later.

So, again, I wonder if a different locale was involved in your Question’s second example. The fix would be to specify explicitly the locale you or your user expects, rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s current momentary default (the default can change at any moment *during* runtime!).

## Cannot confirm problem

```
System.out.println( System.getProperty( "java.version" ) );
System.out.println( Locale.getDefault().toString() );

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.AUGUST , 30 );

Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E d MMM yyyy" , locale );
String output = ld.format( f );

System.out.println( output );
```

When run in Java 10.0.2 via the OpenJDK-based [Zulu JVM](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) by [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) in IntelliJ 2018.3 on a MacBook Pro Retina under macOS High Sierra, I get:

> 10.0.2
>
> en_US
>
> Thu 30 Aug 2018

For Java 8, see this same [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/8c1lSD). Be aware that the JVM used in IdeOne.com is fixed to a single Locale only, `Locale.US`.

> en_US
>
> 1.8.0_112
>
> output: Thu 30 Aug 2018

### Australia

Here is an example of how your output is the norm in some other English-speaking locales, such as Australia.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.AUGUST , 30 );

Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "AU" );  // "en-AU" is English Australia.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E d MMM yyyy" , locale );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

> Thu. 30 Aug. 2018

Comment: Hmmm perhaps it's the JVM I'm using (HotSpot)

Comment: Thank you @BasilBourque it is my Aus Locale

Comment: @LeahEramo Glad to see a diagnosis. Lesson learned: **Always specify your desired/expected `Locale` and `ZoneId`**, even if that means *explicitly* asking for the current default with `Locale.getDefault` & `ZoneId.systemDefault`. Your call to `LocalDate.now` should be passing a `ZoneId` to avoid this same kind of problem/confusion: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Australia/Canberra" ) )`

Comment: @BasilBourque makes much more sense now :) on the other side of it, I am fond of those detailed explanations from you anyway.